# C# out keyword cannot assign to local variable

Tags: c#, out

One of my methods accepts an `out int i` as a parameter. I need to get the value of this variable and assign it to a local variable.

Consider the following simple console application which demonstrates the issue:.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Other o = new Other();
            int i = 5; 
            o.Demo(out i);
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Other
    {
        public void Demo(out int i)
        {
            // i = 10; Uncomment this to fix it (although this would not be an option)
            int k = i;            
        }
    }
```

I cannot assign the variable i to k (in the Demo method). Does any one have an explanation (and a work around :) ).

**EDIT**

The above is just a contrived example of what I'm trying to do: in live, the problem is I'm re-writting code and at this stage, I'm not able to change the "out" as it's one of the parameters of the constructor which is referenced by many, many other projects! I assume this may mean I'm stuffed

Comment: In this example, you do not need the `out` keyword. The usage of `out` on the `int i` parameter of `Demo()` requires that `i` be defined within that function before it returns.

Comment: Why are you using `out` at all in this example?

Comment: Just to provide a simple, easy on the eye version of what I'm doing - my actual project is vast - in the above example I wouldn't use out, it's just to show that I'm trying to push the out value to a local variable.

Comment: You cannot assign `i` to `k` *because* it is an `out`.  Why can you not change to `ref`?  Or, if you need to access the value of a variable only in some cases, perhaps you need an overload.

Comment: Then just pass it through. Why would you want to use `out` for this at all?

Comment: I totally agree - the problem is I'm re-writting code and at this stage, I'm not able to change the "out" as it's one of the parameters of the constructor which is referenced by many, many other projects! I assume this may mean I'm stuffed!

Comment: @DaveRook: what about creating an overload that passes the value in, instead of trying to re-use the same parameter?

Comment: Simply because it's referenced by many many projects and NO documentation - but you're right, I may have to bite the bullet and update the calls to this constructor!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of `out` is that you **must** assign a value to the passed in `out` variable.

If, as your comments suggests, this is **not** an option, then you should not be using `out` for this.

In order to assign the value, just pass in the value as normal:

```
class Other
{
    public void Demo(int i)
    {
        int k = i;            
    }
}
```

---

Now that you have clarified your use case, I would say that you still need to refactor the `out` from the constructor. To start, look at overloading the constructor - have an overload that you can use without `out` and start changing the call sites to the one with `out` parameters until you have cleared them all out.

Comment: I totally agree - the problem is I'm re-writting code and at this stage, I'm not able to change the "out" as it's one of the parameters of the constructor which is referenced by many, many other projects! I assume this may mean I'm stuffed!

Comment: @DaveRook - You will need to remove the `out` from the constructor and all call sites, or provide an overload that doesn't have `out`, at least to start with (possibly with a different parameter type/order/number so overload resolution can work).

Comment: @DaveRook - You really should have stated pretty much your whole comment as part of the question. It is vital context - instead of getting so many answers as to the _why_ and "don't do that", you would have gotten something more pertinent.

Comment: = yes, I have updated now to reflect this; Sorry, sometimes it's hard to write a good question and takes a few attempts (sadly at other people's time - apologies)

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this will be more obvious if we change to:

```
Other o = new Other();
int i;
o.Demo(out i);
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

You'll notice that `i` is not "definitely assigned" *before* the call, and is "definitely assigned" *after* the call. More generally, as a consequence, an `out` parameter is not "definitely assigned" on entry to a method body. You must assign a value to the parameter:

- before you try to read it (if at all)
- before exit (excluding exceptions)

If you want to pass a value *in* as well, use `ref` instead of `out`.

Note that *technically* `ref` and `out` are identical in terms of implementation; the special treatment of definite assignment is a *compiler feature*, intended to avoid us having to initialize with dummy values, for example:

```
int i = 0; // why zero? this zero is useless and never used!
if(int.TryParse(s, out i)) {...}
```

better:

```
int i;
if(int.TryParse(s, out i)) {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, `out` means that the variable comes into the method *uninitialized*, so it must be initialized before you use it.

The meaning of `out` is that the variable is set by the procedure. For your code, it's essentially the same as

```
int Demo()
{
    return ...;
}
```

Note that returning the value as in the example above is usually preferred over returning through `out` parameter.

Comment: Hence why REF would be better I assume?

Comment: @Dave: depends on what you are going to achieve. `ref` means that the variable comes in initialized, and its changes are visible outside as well.

Comment: @DaveRook No, in this context it shouldn't be `out` or `ref`, it should just be a regular pass-by-value.

Answer (score 2):

The point of `out` is that the value is coming *out* of the method, not going in.  The reason why the c# compiler is preventing you from doing this is exactly the same reason that it prevents the following from compiling - `i` is uninitialised

int i;
   int k = i;

If you want to pass a value into this method using this parameter then you need to either use `ref` (so that a value is passed in *and* out), or just remove the `out` entirely (so that a value is only passed into this method)

Answer (score 0):

That is the whole point of *out*. You *must* assign a value to it before the function returns. If you don't like this behavior, either skip it entirely or use the *ref* keyword instead.